# $D$-decomposition theory

Tags: reference-request, control-theory

I'm looking for a book in english (all i can find is in  russian) with a good explanation of this method. I would like to find some theorems about the fact that in each region is characterized by the same number of unstable characteristic roots. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you are already aware of this article, but here it goes: Gryazina, E.N. *[The D-Decomposition Theory](https://doi.org/10.1023/B:AURC.0000049874.93222.2c)*, Automation and Control Theory (2004) 65: 1872. And there is also this survey article: Gryazina, E.N., Polyak, B.T. & Tremba, A.A. *[D-decomposition technique state-of-the-art](https://doi.org/10.1134/S0005117908120011)*, Automation and Control Theory (2008) 69: 1991.